# What is wrong with my binding?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

*Before we start I would like to point out that this is day zero using html / js and knockout so I may just have misunderstood how it all works together.*

I have made a simple test webapi so I can get to grips with knockout. It is all working so far but for the binding `<span data-bind="text:currentMember().name"></span>` which I cannot seem to get to work.

The Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ViewModels/indexViewModel.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Content">
        <section>
            <p>Member Number: </p>  <input id="memberNumber" type="text" />
            <p>Pin: </p>  <input id="memberPin" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Get" data-bind="click: getMember" />
        </section>
        <span data-bind="text:currentMember().name"></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The ViewModel

```
function IndexViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.currentMember = ko.observable();

self.getMember = function () {

    var memberNumber = $('#memberId').val();
    var memberPin = $('#memberPin').val();

    if (memberNumber == '' || memberPin == '') {
        memberNumber = '372-001100-134';
        memberPin = '123456';
    }

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:25979/api/members/GetMemberByNumberAndPin",
        data: {
            memberNumber: memberNumber,
            pin: memberPin
        },
        success: function (serviceResponse) {
            if (!serviceResponse.hasAlerts) {
                self.currentMember(serviceResponse.body);
                alert(self.currentMember().name);
            }
        }
    });
};
}

ko.applyBindings(new IndexViewModel());
```

EDIT: I have changed the code and now the alert does indeed work but the html binding is still not updating.

Comment: self.currentMember(serviceResponse.body);

Comment: Other then the 
`self.currentMember(serviceResponse.body);` You can use the [value binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) for your inputs memberNumber , memberNumber to simplify your getMember function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared `currentMember` as an observable. And to set the value of an observable, you need to invoke it as a function. So try `self.currentMember(serviceResponse.body)` instead. If you do `self.currentMember = seviceResponse.body` as you do, you will essentially re-define the `currentMember` variable as a regular non-observable variable.

Check the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) for further explanation.

Comment: I have changed my code to reflect this. The alert now works as expected but the databinding on the span doesnt.

Comment: @McDonnellDean You need to initialize your observable with an empty object `self.currentMember = ko.observable({});` because by default it is undefinied and when your binding `text:currentMember().name` is parsed it tries to call `name` on undefinied which throws an error. You can see the error in your browser's javascript console.

Comment: @nemesv That did it! Cheers, I am brand new to JS an Knockout and thought it might be pretty much a silly thing like that!